# EntityFieldQuery in rules - no result

Tags: rules, database

I try to set a new variable in rules. I try to get nid of a node selected by efq like this:

```
<?php
$termid = $node->field_terms['und'][0]['tid'];
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'mybundle')
->fieldCondition('field_terms', 'tid', $termid)

$result = $query->execute();
$nid = array_keys($result['node'])->nid;
print $nid;
?>
```

The problem is that no matter I do, I am not getting nid output. Can anybody help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`array_keys($result['node'])` isn't going to return an object that you can select a `nid` property from; it's going to return an array of nids that have `$termid` tagged in its `field_terms` field. If you're just looking for the first nid in the query results you can do `$nid = array_keys($result['node'])[0];`

Comment: HI, yes I am looking for first nid. But even with your code print $nid is not showing anything.

Comment: Check that the EFQ is actually returning results. Your code is assuming that `$termid` is not null and that the `mybundle` node type is tagged with `$termid`.

Comment: HI, yes it is working. If I use ->count(); the results return 1 (the result is always one node in my case). I just need to get the nid out of it:) I tried also dpm(entity_get_info()); or dpm(field_info_fields()); - returns nothing.